# Getting ConcurrentModificationException when modify only the object properties inside a list

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, concurrentmodification

I'm trying to iterate through an `ArrayList` of objects in two different threads.

For an example lets say type of the objects in the list will be `Bottle` and two threads that are trying to access that list will be `Buyer` and `Seller`.

I'm trying to update the Bottle objects using both methods in the threads. I'm not adding or removing objects from the list. (both methods are `static` and `synchronized`)

And there are multiple threads running of both `Buyer` and `Seller`.

Is it possible that I get this `exception` because one of the the `Seller` thread is trying to update the same `Bottle` object while one of the Buyer thread updating it?

Just to get an better idea, list and methods are kinda like below.

```
class Seller {
    static synchronized void someMethod(List<Bottle> bottles) {
        for (Bottle bottle:bottles)
        {
            //some code
            bottle.updateAPropertyInsideBottleObject(newValue);
            //more code
        }
    }
}

class Buyer {
    static synchronized void someMethod(List<Bottle> bottles) {
        for (Bottle bottle:bottles)
        {
            //some code
            bottle.updateAPropertyInsideBottleObject(newValue);
            //more code
        }
    }
}
```

What would be a good solution to avoid this?

Comment: If you want us to explain why you get a specific exception with a specific code, you need to post tht specific code and that exception stack trace. Post a complete minimal example reproducing he problem.

Comment: All we can say is that no, the exception should not be caused by iterating the same list in both concurrent thread, and that synchronizing these methods serves no purpose since it doesn't prevent two threads from iterating the list and modifying the objects concurrently: they synchronize on a different monitor.

Comment: The real code is complex and it's impossible to post it in here. That's why I have explained the scenario I'm facing with an example. Is it the same list as you said? Since I'm modifying the objects(by modifying a property) inside the list?

Comment: Yes, it's the same list, with the same elements. The state of the elements is changed. That doesn't change the state of the list, and it thus won't throw any exception.

Comment: Thank you for trying to present a minimal example. Unfortunately there's not enough information here to diagnose the problem. You've cut out some crucial detail that matters. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Sand If you're interested in doing a more in-depth research about the problem you are trying to solve *(Consumer-Producer Problem)*, I suggest reading [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-31/index.html) from Oracle. It's a good read.